# Break a long assignment into two lines in Python

Tags: python, pep8

I have the following code:

```
This.is.a.supper.long.name = This.is.another.supper.long.name
```

Currently the only method I know is to escape the newline:

```
This.is.a.supper.long.name = \
    This.is.another.supper.long.name
```

Is there any elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches.

```
 common = This.is
 common.a.supper.long.name = common.another.supper.long.name
```

If that doesn't help, you can

```
 name = This.is.another.supper.long.name
 This.is.a.supper.long.name = name
```

or

```
 setName(This, getName(This))
```

where the methods allow to hide the long access path. This becomes even more readable when you can change `This`:

```
 This.setName(This.getName())
```